# What must I do to prevent Perl from complaining that "using a hash as a reference is deprecated"?

Tags: perl, syntax

The code below is from an old Perl script.

```
print "%{@{$noss}[$i]}->{$sector} \n\n";
```

How should I rewrite the code above so that Perl does not complain that "using a hash as a reference is deprecated"? I have tried all sorts of way but I still couldn't quite get the hang of what the Perl compiler want me to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> print "%{@{$noss}[$i]}->{$sector} \n\n";
> ```

should be nothing more than

```
print "$noss->[$i]{$sector} \n\n";
```

or even

```
print "$$noss[$i]{$sector} \n\n";
```

without all that rigamarole.

Comment: Rigamarole indeed. It's never fun to inherit legacy code. What a breath of fresh air. It's all clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Guessing that $noss is a reference to an array of hash references, you can build a correct expression by following the simple rule of replacing 
what would normally be an array or hash name (not including the $/@/%) with an expression giving a reference in curly braces.

So your array element, normally `$foo[$i]`, becomes `${$noss}[$i]`.  That expression is itself a hashref, so to get an element from that hash, instead of `$foo{$sector}`, you use `${ ${$noss}[$i] }{$sector}`.

This can also appear in various other forms, such as `$noss->[$i]{$sector}`; see http://perlmonks.org?node=References+quick+reference for simple to understand rules.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with ysth and tchrist, and want to reiterate that `$noss->[$i]{$sector}` really is the best option for you. This syntax is more readable since it shows clearly that `$noss` is a reference and that you are taking the `$i`th element of it and further the `$sector` key from that element.

In terms of teaching to fish rather than giving out fish: you should read [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Using-References) and specifically the "use rules". Understanding these two "use rules" along with the extra "arrow rule" (yep only 3 rules) will give you a much better grasp on how to get going with references.