# Using hash as a reference is deprecated

Tags: perl, hash

I searched SO before asking this question, I am completely new to this and have no idea how to handle these errors. By this I mean Perl language.

When I put this

```
%name->{@id[$#id]} = $temp;
```

I get the error `Using a hash as a reference is deprecated`

I tried

```
$name{@id[$#id]} = $temp
```

but couldn't get any results back.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of variable is "name"? Where is it first initialized and what kind of data does it contain? Can't help you without knowing. Although, I will say that -> is the dereference operator, it only works on $scalars that contain a reference, not %hashes, thus the error.

Comment: I initialize it at the top of the code by doing `my %name;`

Comment: @Grigor Try ` $name{$id[$#id]} = $temp `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928523/what-must-i-do-to-prevent-perl-from-complaining-that-using-a-hash-as-a-referenc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265673/perl-using-a-hash-as-a-reference-is-deprecated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705876/error-in-perl-using-a-hash-as-a-reference-is-deprecated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to access an element of hash `%name` is `$name{'key'}`. The syntax `%name->{'key'}` was valid in Perl v5.6 but has since been deprecated.

Similarly, to access the last element of array `@id` you should write `$id[$#id]` or, more simply, `$id[-1]`.

Your second variation should work fine, and your inability to retrieve the value has an unrelated reason.

Write

```
$name{$id[-1]} = 'test';
```

and

```
print $name{$id[-1]};
```

will display `test` correctly

Answer (score 4):

```
%name->{...}
```

has always been buggy. It doesn't do what it should do. As such, it now warns when you try to use it. The proper way to index a hash is

```
$name{...}
```

as you already believe.

---

Now, you say

```
$name{@id[$#id]}
```

doesn't work, but if so, it's because of an error somewhere else in the code. That code most definitely works

```
>perl -wE"@id = qw( a b c ); %name = ( a=>3, b=>4, c=>5 ); say $name{@id[$#id]};"
Scalar value @id[$#id] better written as $id[$#id] at -e line 1.
5
```

As the warning says, though, the proper way to index an array isn't

```
@id[...]
```

It's actually

```
$id[...]
```

---

Finally, the easiest way to get the last element of an array is to use index `-1`. The means your code should be

```
$name{ $id[-1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

The popular answer is to just not dereference, but that's not correct.  In other words `%$hash_ref->{$key}` and `%$hash_ref{$key}` are not interchangeable. The former is required to access a hash reference nested as an element in another hash reference.

For many moons it has been common place to nest hash references.  In fact there are several modules that parse data and store it in this kind of data structure.  Instantly depreciating the behavior without module updates was not a good thing.  At times my data is trapped in a nested hash and the only way to get it is to do something like.

```
$new_hash_ref = $target_hash_ref->{$key1}
$new_hash_ref2 = $target_hash_ref->{$key2}
$new_hash_ref3 = $target_hash_ref->{$key3}
```

because I can't

```
foreach my $i(keys(%$target_hash_ref)) {
    foreach(%$target_hash_ref->{$i} {
        #do stuff with $_
    }
}
```

anymore.

Yes the above is a little strange, but creating new variables just to avoid accessing a data structure in a certain way is worse.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score -2):

If you want one item from an array or hash use $.  For a list of items use @ and % respectively.  Your use of @ as a reference returned a list instead of an item which perl may have interpreted as a hash.

This code demonstrates your reference of a hash of arrays.

```
#!/usr/bin perl -w
my %these = ( 'first'=>101,
             'second'=>102,
           );
my @those = qw( first second );
print $these{$those[$#those]};
```

prints '102'

Comment: This is just wrong. You cannot use `%` to extract a list from anything. And Perl will never interpret a list as a hash.

Comment: @Borodin  We may be arguing symantics but `$ perl -e '%these=qw(foo 0 bar 1);print join(":", %these)'` works fine on both counts.

Comment: @Borodin Perl obviously did not interpret the list as a hash as it through an error.